# Should I upgrade my LAN setup for better server hosting?

Tags: networking, lan, hosting

My current setup, Wave 7 Optics LMG-441E Gateway, going into a Linksys going into a WRT54G Router, with a Cisco SE1500 Switch. I'm running a Minecraft server with a wired connection to the switch, wired to the router, wired to the gateway.

I'm not well versed in networking, and I've noticed we're experiencing some latency issues on the server, and I'm under the impression that upgrading my LAN won't help me any. I have a 15MBps down/ 5MBps up connection. I wish it was better, but I'm not fortunate enough to live in a place with a good broadband connection.

With such a low Internet speed, would upgrading my LAN help at all? I was told from my ISP that the Gateway has a 100Mbit/s rating. So my inclination is no, it wouldn't help at all. I'm just trying to find where the bottleneck is, and if the problem is with my connection, or a few of the players.

Sidenote: Where are some good resources to learn about networking and server hosting in general?

Answer (score 0):

Your inclination is likely correct, upgrading your LAN hardware probably won't make much of a difference if your clients are connecting from the WAN. It's all about [bottlenecks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates), and in this case your bottleneck is your Internet connection, especially the 5 MBps upload speed.

On the topic of determining if either yourself or your friends are more slow, there isn't a hard and fast way to determine this. You could all visit http://www.speedtest.net/ and compare results, but bare in mind that this is only an estimation.

You may want to review how your Server performs within your LAN. Invite your friends over for the weekend and have everyone connect to the same LAN. It may be that your network isn't the only cause of lag. You may have already [visited this site](http://minecraftserverhq.com/blog/can%27t-keep-up/), but it recommends the following in order to improve Minecraft server performance:

> .... Easiest thing to do to is lower your
>   view-distance setting in your server.properties file. The furthest
>   view-distance you can have is 15, while the shortest is 3. If you
>   really want to reduce lag, try the 3 setting and see if you can
>   tolerate it. If that's too short, keep increasing the view distance
>   until you can see far enough that it doesn't bother you. ...
>
> MORE POWER Ok, so be cautions here. This is a bit of a confusing
>   topic. Something you have to realize is that Minecraft Servers can
>   only run on ONE CORE of a processor. Upgrading to a 6-core monster
>   won't do you any good. However, if you get a processor that is faster
>   per core, then you can really up your player capacity without adding
>   any lag. ...